# Is Cheney the same character as Wraith?

Tags: shannara

I just started reading ***Armageddon's Children***, and there is a dog named Cheney. From the description it sounds like Wraith, or at least a descendant. Is there anything anywhere that confirms this?

Comment: I haven't read it, but my gut feeling says you should leave this question until after you've finished the book.

Comment: @MrLister: Yeah. That's my gut feeling as well.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

*Wraith* was absorbed by Nest and became one with her during the events of *"A Knight Of The Word*". Wraith was a creature of magic

> made by Nest's father who was a demon.

*Cheney* was found as a stray dog and adopted by Hawk. He was just a big strong dog with no special abilities (nothing beyond the abilities of a very good and loyal dog).